# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-manager

Trying to build my android project using

`react-native run-android`

But, I keep getting this same error:

```
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK 
components:
[Android SDK Platform 26, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and 
complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio 
SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one 
workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export- 
licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

What I have tried:

1. I tried using `sdkmanager --licenses` to accept all licenses
2. I updated my SDK
3. I cleaned my project using `git clean  -d  -fx`
4. I made sure to have the latest Android SDK installed

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you build this React-native app by Android Studio.

Use Android Studio open Android project in folder `/android` of your project.

After project open Android Studio will suggest `"update"`, `need skip`.
With `dialog for download SDK, you accept and continue`.

When finish setup you can build your RN Android by menu `Build\Build APK` or direct run app by menu `Run\Run App`
[image]
[image]

Comment: It works for me. I built the APK successfully in Android Studio, then I continued working with VS Code. I guess I just needed some things set up which Android Studio did in the background. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, Android Studio will do many thing in background. And build with Android Studio we can trace building bug easier. If this answer is correct please upvote and mark correct. Thanks